# How to add an asterisk indicating the existence of statistically significant differences in a plot created with plot_profiles {tidySEM}?

Tags: r, plot, graph, tidymodels

I am estimating a latent profile analysis. I made the graph with the following code:

```
y1[1:158, ] %>%
  select(BIEPSA, IAB, IDS, AFN_EMO, EVT_EMO, EEA_EMO, REP_RAC, RLG_RAC, FSP_RAC, BAS_RAC) %>%
  single_imputation() %>%
  estimate_profiles(2) %>%
  plot_profiles(add_line = TRUE, sd = FALSE, rawdata = FALSE, bw = FALSE, ci = NULL)
```

It results in the left figure.

However, I want to put an asterisk over the pair of points for each category that shows statistically significant differences. Something like what is shown in the right figure.

Actually I have no idea about how to solve this problem

Comment: Hi, can you provide a reproducible example? We don't have your data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.